# jsdom - document.querySelector enabled, but is missing from document

Tags: node.js, jsdom, native-methods

I would like to use JSDom to perform some server-wise DOM manipulation. However, despite explcitly enabling querySelector, it is undefined in the documents created:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

// Yep, we've got QuerySelector turned on
jsdom.defaultDocumentFeatures = {
  QuerySelector: true
};

var dom = jsdom.defaultLevel;

var document = jsdom.jsdom("<html><body><h1>Hello StackOverflow</h1></body></html>"),
window = document.createWindow();
```

However:

```
console.log(document.querySelector)
```

Returns

```
undefined
```

How can I make document.querySelector work properly using jsdom?

Comment: Why are you don't use jQuery?

Comment: @NiLL Because JQuery has a lot of code I don't need and querySelector is provided out of the box in most of the environments where the code will run (ie, all current browsers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) documentation, here the updated code for version 16.6.0:

```
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");

const dom = new JSDOM("<html><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>");
const document = dom.window.document;

console.log(document.querySelector);
```

Comment: Going to change the accepted answer to this one to keep StackOverflow up to date.

Answer (score 14):

Found the answer to this one myself.

JSDom has a 'default document' as well as support for multiple additional documents.

My original understanding was that enabling QuerySelector on the default document would enable it on all documents. This was incorrect.

I needed to enable QuerySelector on the (non-default) document I was creating.

Working code below:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

var dom = jsdom.defaultLevel;

// QuerySelector must be turned on on the specificdocument we're creating
var document = jsdom.jsdom("<html><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>", null, {
  features: {
    QuerySelector: true
  }
}),
window = document.createWindow();
```

Running

```
console.log(document.querySelector)
```

Now shows the function exists.

Comment: Not working in `9.2.1` at least: `TypeError: document.createWindow is not a function`

Comment: any idea how i would select elements in an electron application if i cant use `document.querySelector`?

Comment: where is this documented?

Comment: @chovy that's an excellent question, but the answer is 8 years ago. Perhaps you could add a link to the current jsdoc documentation?

Comment: @mikemaccana I've added the code for the latest version and the link to the repository in my answer.